# Define optional distances to use with `to path` of TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments

I would like in the code below to have the possibility to give optional arguments for the shift distances. What is the best way to do that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\tikzset{
    aczigzag/.style = {
        to path = {
            ([xshift = 0mm] \tikztostart)
             |- ([xshift = 3mm, yshift = 5mm] \tikztotarget.north)
             -- ([xshift = 3mm] \tikztotarget.north)
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
  (input) {INPUT};

  \node[right] at ($(input) + (2.5,0)$)
  (right) {right};

  \node[below of = input, node distance = 4cm]
  (output) {OUPUT};

  \path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag] (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what pgf keys are for. You can store the distances in such keys, and modify them in a path.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\tikzset{
    aczigzag/.style = {
        to path = {
            ([xshift = 0mm] \tikztostart)
             |- ([xshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/x}, yshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/y}] \tikztotarget.north)
             -- ([xshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/x}] \tikztotarget.north)
        }
    },aczigzag/.cd,x/.initial=3mm,y/.initial=5mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
  (input) {INPUT};

  \node[right] at ($(input) + (2.5,0)$)
  (right) {right};

  \node[below of = input, node distance = 4cm]
  (output) {OUPUT};

  \path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag] (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
  (input) {INPUT};

  \node[right] at ($(input) + (2.5,0)$)
  (right) {right};

  \node[below of = input, node distance = 4cm]
  (output) {OUPUT};

  \path[draw,aczigzag/x=5mm,aczigzag/y=12mm] (right) to[aczigzag] (output);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here you could equally well use

```
\path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag,aczigzag/x=5mm,aczigzag/y=12mm] (output);
```

It might even more convenient to let the argument of the style make these changes. Then

```
 \path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag={x=5mm,y=12mm}] (output);
```

will change the horizontal distance to 5mm and the vertical one to 12mm.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\tikzset{
    aczigzag/.style = {/utils/exec=\tikzset{aczigzag/.cd,#1},
        to path = {
            ([xshift = 0mm] \tikztostart)
             |- ([xshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/x}, yshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/y}] \tikztotarget.north)
             -- ([xshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aczigzag/x}] \tikztotarget.north)
        }
    },aczigzag/.cd,x/.initial=3mm,y/.initial=5mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
  (input) {INPUT};

  \node[right] at ($(input) + (2.5,0)$)
  (right) {right};

  \node[below of = input, node distance = 4cm]
  (output) {OUPUT};

  \path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag] (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
  (input) {INPUT};

  \node[right] at ($(input) + (2.5,0)$)
  (right) {right};

  \node[below of = input, node distance = 4cm]
  (output) {OUPUT};

  \path[draw] (right) to[aczigzag={x=5mm,y=12mm}] (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko Did you read the question? (I am not sure if I understand it but according to my understanding the OP only wants the possibility to change the distances on the spot, not add a new syntax.)

Comment: i read, but, well, i will delete my comment.